# Swift how to upload image to server inside model

Tags: c#, ios, .net, swift

I want to send image to server with some information. The server side is accepting request inside the model so there are 2 challenges to me.

1. How can I represent Image into my modal class
2. What file type should be use to match exact to server side as server side is using HttpFileBase

**So following is my model in swift**

```
public class ReceiptServiceModel: Codable {


  var   Id : String = ""
  var   UserId : Int64 = 0
  var   Name : String? = ""
  var   Notes : String? = ""
  var ReceiptFile : Data? = nil //<== this is the image representation type i can think for image file.

  }
```

**Following is a model at server side (.Net)**

```
public class ReceiptServiceModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public HttpFileBase ReceiptFile { get; set; } //<== This one is confusing me....


}
```

So what should be use to wrap a file/Images into Model class and what should I use to match the exact type on server side. Check the comments in code snippet for clear view of fields that is creating confusions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I understood that you are trying to send the image to the server using a POST request.
To send the image to the server using post either you can use "Form-Data" or you need to convert your image to Base64 or blob format so you can add that in your JSON file which the server can accept.

use below url for how to convert image to blob:
https://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/current/swift/blob.html

install pod from below link:
https://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/current/swift/gs-install.html

can try below sample code:

```
 import CouchbaseLite-Swift

 public class ReceiptServiceModel: Codable {
  var   Id : String = ""
  var   UserId : Int64 = 0
  var   Name : String? = ""
  var   Notes : String? = ""
  var ReceiptFile : Blob? = nil
}

func convertImageToBlob() {
  guard let appleImage = UIImage(systemName: "edit") else {
     return
  }

  let imageData = appleImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)!

  let blob = Blob(contentType: "image/jpeg", data: imageData)

  let model = ReceiptServiceModel()
  model.ReceiptFile = blob
 }
```

Comment: but I need to send the model, not directly in request @msusare

Comment: how are you sending the model to the server? For recipientFile you can use blob as a type to share in the model.

Comment: @msuare i have not sent any request yet, and I have created a model as such shown in question. I did not have any clue to go next.

Comment: can you please show with example how can i convert it to blob. I opened the link that you attached in your answer but I am not getting it right

Comment: use let blob = Blob(contentType: "image/jpeg", data: data)

Comment: check my updated answer where I have updated steps.